# py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --cov-report --cov=

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am running this test case command below

```
py.test --cov-report term-missing --cov=pipelines/core/comp/plugins/abc/ --noconftest pipelines/core/comp/test/plugins/abc/test_abc_crawler_task.py -vv
```

But getting the following error :

```
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --cov-report --cov=pipelines/core/comp/plugins/abc/ pipelines/core/comp/test/plugins/abc/test_abc_v4_crawler_task.py
  inifile: /home/udocker/piper/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/udocker/piper
```

Comment: Did you install `pytest-cov`?

Answer (score 11):

You need to install `pytest-cov` with

```
pip3 install pytest-cov
```